# create observables from an array of data and chain all these together

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following requirement:

- I have an array of data
- For each item in the array I need to perform a call resulting in an Observable
- I need to chain all these observables together
- If one of the observables results in a false response I need to return false

  - further observables should not have to proceed

The context is a guard in Angular which uses canActivate() returning an Observable<boolean>

I want to avoid following construction in the guard (pseudo code):

```
// the actions to check
var actions = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

canActivate() : Observable<boolean> {
    return this.performAction(actions[0]).subscribe(result => {
      if(result){
        this.performAction(actions[1]).subscribe(result2 => {
           if(result2){
               this.performAction(actions[2]).subscribe(result3 => {
                 ...
               };
           }
       });
   }
   //result = false;
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

const actions = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const performAction = (action): Observable<boolean> => {
  if (action === 'y') {
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
  return Observable.of(true);
}

const observable = Observable.from(actions)
  .concatMap(a => performAction(a))
  .multicast(new ReplaySubject(1),
    s => s.takeWhile(result => result !== false).concat(s.take(1))
  );

observable.subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-hnzwtt?file=index.ts

The most important part is the `multicast` operator that passes through everything until it receives `false`. Then this `false` value is the last one before completing the chain (thanks to `concat`).

The output is:

```
true
false
```

Comment: The performAction would always return Observable<boolean> and I need to assign the entire expression to one Observable<boolean> (which is true in case everything returned true). How would I go about to do this given this code? thanks

Comment: @stephan.peters Then just store it in a variable, see my edit.

Comment: We are getting near :) But I get following typescript error and I also see that on the live demo: 
Argument of type 'ReplaySubject<{}>' is not assignable to parame
ter of type '(this: Observable<{}>) => Subject<{}>'.
[0]   Type 'ReplaySubject<{}>' provides no match for the signature '(this: Observable<{}>): Subject<{}>'.

Comment: The error on stackblitz is actually wrong, it thinks the parameter needs to be a function but you can also pass a `Subject` instance. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/multicast.ts#L9
You an replace the Subject with `() => new ReplaySubject(1)` and it'll work as well.

Comment: This answer does not seem to fulfill the OP requirement "further observables should not have to proceed". As illustrated here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-amnqpd?file=index.ts

Comment: I think I found the solution to the "further observables should not have to proceed" requirement: ".concatMap(a => performAction(a)).takeWhile(result => result !== false);" -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-85mw81?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer for rxjs 7.x (7.5.4)**

This answer does also satisfy the OP's requirement of:

> - further observables should not have to proceed

To get this working I had to use a new parameter added to the takeWhile operator(rxjs 6+) which returns the value that caused the takeWhile operator to complete the observable.

Working code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-85mw81?file=index.ts

```
  const arrayOfValues = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

  const performAction = (action): Observable<boolean> => {
    if (action === 'y') {
      return of(false);
    }
    return of(true);
  }

  const observable = of(...arrayOfValues).pipe(
    concatMap(a => performAction(a)),
    takeWhile(result => result !== false, true),
    takeLast(1));
    
  observable.subscribe(console.log);
```